# Accessing column's `default` attribute after reflection

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

As part of a sanity check I want to check if each column comes with a `default` value or function. When I create the table I can access this information through `table.columns` `default` attribute.

At the moment I use "reflection" to access/reconnect existing tables.

But when I try to access the `default` attribute of the columns, after having using reflection, the `default` attribute is set to `None`.

```python
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, MetaData, create_engine
engine = create_engine(postgresql+psycopg2://XXX)
metadata = MetaData(engine)

table_name ='test'
table = Table(table_name, metadata,
Column('id', Integer,  primary_key=True),
Column('value', Integer, default=42))
table.create(engine)
for c in table.columns:
    print c.name, repr(c.default)

print '`reattaching using reflection`'
metadata = MetaData(engine)
metadata.reflect()
table_reloaded = metadata.tables[table_name]
for c in table_reloaded.columns:
    print c.name, repr(c.default)
```

Output:

```
id None
value ColumnDefault(42)
`reattaching using reflection`
id None
value None
```

Comment: `default` is the Python default. You want `server_default`.

Comment: @univerio, If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` is the Python-level default. SQLAlchemy reflection puts the database column default in `server_default`:

```
for c in table_reloaded.columns:
    print c.name, repr(c.server_default)
```